# MySQL Trigger to create a row in a different table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I know there must be a simple way to do this but I couldn't find one. I want to create a trigger that basically, when a row is created in table1, creates a new row in table2 with a foreign key of the id of table1. what is the general syntax for this? thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CREATE TRIGGER Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-trigger.html)

For example -

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
  AFTER INSERT
  ON table1
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO table2(id) VALUES(NEW.id);
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `create_t1` AFTER INSERT ON `table1` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO table2
SET t1ID = NEW.ID, 
    when = Now();
END;
```